# req.flash not showing message

Tags: node.js, express, flash-message

I'm using Handlebars in my express project. and I use req.flash() method but it won't Show up in my hbs file.

Here's my Code :

```
 req.flash('message','Tag already exists');
 res.redirect('/p/tags/add');
```

In .hbs file :

```
{{#if message}}
<h1>Tag Already ِExists</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Also in my app.js :

```
app.use(flash());
```

What Seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us package.json file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your flash message inside your redirected URL like this:

```
app.get('/p/tags/add', function(req, res){
  res.render('yourhbsfile', { message: req.flash('message') });
});
```

**EDIT:** So to clarify about the confusion on flash message, it can be set from anywhere before redirecting to any route or inside any middleware before using res.render() and can propagate that message inside `req` or `request` object. you may print `req` and check `flash` object for better understanding.

Comment: You mean there is no way to use in res.redirect?

Comment: @HamedJavaheri, no. What Harsh means is that you need to execute the `flash` functionality in the redirected route handler, but not before it. If you put your `flash` as the very first thing in the redirected router, then it's still gonna be executed before anything else, when the app redirects to the route.

Comment: looking at res.redirect API Reference it doesn't accept any other argument except `status` and `path`. So I guess you can't do it with res.redirect()

Comment: Then how to use now message in handleabr side?

Answer (score 0):

It's true you can't add `flash` with redirection.
You have to execute `flash` function before redirection and then you have to use it inside the render function.

```
boo = (req, res) => {
    req.flash("error", "This is an error!");
    return res.redirect("/index");
}
```

- Im using Routes, when viewing the /index page the `indexPage` function is executed.

Render function to view /index page.

```
indexPage = (req, res) => {
    let message = req.flash();
    res.render("index", {
      message: message,
    });
}
```

And how to view the data in Handlebar `index.hbs`

```
{{#if message.error}} 
    {{{message.error}}} 
{{/if}}
```